# Colorized tabs in JetBrains Rider plugin?

Tags: visual-studio, jetbrains-ide, rider

In Visual Studio you can have per-project colorized tabs with the [Productivity Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2015). It basically paints the tabs of the same project in the same color. Which makes the navigation a bit easier. It also looks like VS [now supports it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/personalize-docs/#flexible-workspace) out of the box.

Is there a JetBrains (Rider) plugin that does the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is something that does it automatically, but you can do it "manually": https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Configuring_Scopes_and_File_Colors.html

1. Define your scopes in **File | Settings... | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes**
2. In **File | Settings... | Appearance & Behavior | File Colors** you can colorize the tabs by scope.

I had to save the settings multiple time to see the UI refresh.